# What is the difference between "maybe" and "may be"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adverbs

What is the difference in meaning and usage between *maybe* and *may be*? Are they synonymous?

Comment: with *maybe*, you'll have two "verbs": "May**be** you **are** right"

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**maybe** is an adverb, meaning perhaps or possibly.

**may be** is a verbal construction, formed of the modal verb *may* and the verb *be*, which can be used in sentences like *“he may be in the office today”*. Note that, if you were to rewrite this sentence with *maybe*, you would say *“maybe he is in the office today”*. Because *maybe* is an adverb, you need to add a verb to the sentence (*is*, a form of *be*, in that case).

Answer (score 16):

*Maybe* is an adverb, with means *possibly* or *perhaps*; *may be* is a verbal phrase.

> Maybe you are wrong.
>   It may be true.

As per the origin, the NOAD reports that the origin of *maybe* is late Middle English, from the phrase *it may be (that)*.