# Is there any difference in certainty between "may be" and "maybe"?

Tags: meaning, differences

In the song [Tonight Again](http://www.eurovision.tv/event/lyrics?event=2083&song=32993), there's a line going

> They may be right but only maybe

I understand that "maybe" is an adverb, while "may be" is a combination of the verbs "may" and "be", as mentioned in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/12849/1420). However, is there any difference in the degree of certainty between the two, as might be suggested by the "but only"?

Comment: Its merely an emphasiser. 'They may be right. But only maybe.' = 'They _may_ be right.', in cases where context demands that the 'may' is being stressed to highlight the uncertainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is.

Consider:

> There's a chance they are right, but only a chance.

The `but only` is just highlighting the lack of absolute certainty. It doesn't imply any difference in probability between the two cases.